# Wordpress on Google App Engine wp-admin trailing slash issue

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a wordpress site on Google App Engine. Everything works, however, if I try to access /wp-admin/ without the trailing slash, the dashboard will load, but the links will 404.

I need to manually add the trailing slash when entering the dashboard. I'm not sure how to solve this since this is GAE.

Example:

I access mysite.com/wp-admin

Links on the sidebar will be mysite.com/edit-post.php (404)

If i add the trailing slash and access the dashboard mysite.com/wp-admin/

the link is now mysite.com/wp-admin/edit-post.php which works fine.

I need it to force the trailing slash when in admin. I've never had this issue before.

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-includes/images/media/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-includes/images/media/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: PROJECT:us-central1:match

runtime_config:
  document_root: wordpress
  skip_lockdown_document_root: true

env_variables:
  WHITELIST_FUNCTIONS: escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,pclose,popen,shell_exec,phpversion,php_uname
```

I'm not sure if there's another file I should include.

Comment: What are a couple examples of paths that are 404'ing?

Comment: Everything in the dashboard. For example, if I click on "posts", the file is edit-posts.php. When I access wp-admin without the trailing slash, it will look for mysite.com/edit-posts.php instead of mysite.com/wp-admin/edit-posts.php

Comment: Try adding a `- url: /wp-admin` handler with the same content as your existing `- url: /wp-admin/` (without the trailing `/`).